# Reset HTML Table data using javascript or Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services, html-table

I m have the following table structure,

```
<table id="tblPtPrtDtl" class="table table-bordered table-striped mb-none">
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>
                                                    <b>File Number </b>
                                                </th>
                                                <th>
                                                    <b>Name </b>
                                                </th>
                                                <th>
                                                    <b>Status </b>
                                                </th>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <span class="prtfilenum"></span>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <span class="prtname"></span>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <span class="prtstatus"></span>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
```

I populate this table using web method (page Method),
this is the JS success function after AJAX call code for it

```
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
            var xml = $(xmlDoc);
            var customers = xml.find("PtPrt");
            var row = $("[id*=tblPtPrtDtl] > tbody tr:last-child").clone(true);
            $("[id*=tblPtPrtDtl] tr").not(':has(th)').remove();
            $.each(customers, function () {
                $(".prtfilenum", row).html($(this).find("PrtFilenum").text());
                $(".prtname", row).html($(this).find("Column1").text());
                $(".prtstatus", row).html($(this).find("PrtStatus").text());
                $("[id*=tblPtPrtDtl]").append(row);
                row = $("[id*=tblPtPrtDtl] > tbody tr:last-child").clone(true);
```

I m trying to empty the table but removing all rows will remove the classes which are needed for populating the table.

I want to clear all the data from the rows and keep only one empty that has the classes intact in it for re-populating the fields when needed.

I tried the following functions but the remove all rows and their classes which prevents me from re-populating the table.

```
$("#tblPtPrtDtl tr").remove();
$("#tblPtPrtDtl tr").detach();
```

thanks

Comment: `$("#tblPtPrtDtl tr").html("");`?

Comment: no sir, did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I have worked around it,
first I generate the table using javascripting, I populate the table with my data. i clear the table by removing its structure completely. by this I can keep using that table with different records without refreshing my page. the code below populate the table in a defined Div area

```
  var tbl = $("<table>").attr("id", "tblPtPrtDtl").addClass("table table-bordered table-striped mb-none");
        var tr1 = $("<tr>").append($("<th>").append($("<b>").text("File Number")))
        .append($("<th>").append($("<b>").text("Name")))
        .append($("<th>").append($("<b>").text("Status")));
        var tr2 = $("<tr>").append($("<td>").append($("<span>").attr("id", "prtfilenum")))
        .append($("<td>").append($("<span>").attr("id", "prtname")))
        .append($("<td>").append($("<span>").attr("id", "prtstatus")));

        tbl.append(tr1);
        tbl.append(tr2);
        if ($('#tblPtPrtDtl').length) { $('#tblPtPrtDtl').remove(); $("#dvTable").append(tbl); } else { $("#dvTable").append(tbl); }
```

to remove it i use

```
if ($('#tblPtPrtDtl').length) { $('#tblPtPrtDtl').remove() }
```

Ref: https://forums.asp.net/post/6132153.aspx